# Linq - what to do when 'Queries with local collections are not supported'

Tags: .net, linq

I'm trying to convert an SQL query to Linq and I get an exception:

*System.NotSupportedException : Queries with local collections are not supported.*

So is there a way to rephrase the query in a 'legal' way?

Thanks for any suggestions,

Anders, Denmark

### PS: I've seen the 'solution' to call .ToList() on any query before calling .Contains() -- but that would just result in four separate queries, right?

At the bottom is my code that fails on execution.

The logical problem I'm trying to solve is to find the 'structures' that a user have access to, either by direct access or by membership of a group that has access. We do not have nested groups.

In other words, the user should have access if any of the following is true:

> - The user created the structure (id is 'stamped into' the structure record).
> - An entry exists in the PermissionUsers table, linking the Permissions Table with the users table.
> - an entry exists in the PermissionGroups table, linking the Permissions table with the Groups table and the user is referenced in
>     the UsersGroups table, linking Users table with the Users table.

Applying permissions/restricting result to accessible items is a relatively new thing and we would like the database to do the heavy pulling ;).

```
[TestFixture]
public class LinqTest : CommandBasedIntegrationTestBase
{
    [Test, Category("SuperIntegration"), RequiresSTAAttribute]
    public void TestThat()
    {
        DbIntegrationTestHelper.SetState();

        var dataContextProvider = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IDataContextProvider>();

        const int userId = 1;

        var environment = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IState>().DatabaseEnvironment;
        var dataClasses1DataContext = dataContextProvider.GetContext(environment);

        var idsByCreator = from r in dataClasses1DataContext.Structures where r.CreatedUserId == userId select r.StructureId;
        var idsByUserAccess = from r in dataClasses1DataContext.PermissionUsers where r.UserId == userId select r.StructureId;
        var idsOfGroupsContainingUser = from r in dataClasses1DataContext.UsersGroups where r.UserId == userId select r.GroupId;
        var idsByGroupAccess = from r in dataClasses1DataContext.PermissionGroups where idsOfGroupsContainingUser.Contains( r.GroupId ) select r.StructureId;


        var res = from s in dataClasses1DataContext.Structures
                  where
                      idsByCreator.Contains(s.StructureId) || 
                      idsByUserAccess.Contains(s.StructureId) ||
                      idsByGroupAccess.Contains(s.StructureId)
                  select s;

        foreach (var structure in res)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(structure.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try to `JOIN`s, `UNION`s

**Example**

```
var ctx = dataContextProvider.GetContext(environment);

var byCreator = from r in ctx.Structures where r.CreatedUserId == userId select r;

var byUserAccess = from r in ctx.PermissionUsers 
                   join s in ctx.Structures on r.StructureId equals s.StructureId
                   where r.UserId == userId select s;

var byGroups = from ug in ctx.UsersGroups 
               join pg in ctx.PermissionGroups on ug.GroupId equals pg.GroupId
               join s in ctx.Structures on pg.StructureId equals s.StructureId
               where ug.UserId == userId select s;

var res = byCreator.Union(byUserAccess).Union(byGroups);
```

*Update*

I have removed unnecessary call to `Distinct()` according to @Magnus comment. Call to `Distinct()` would be necessary only if `Concat()` instead of `Union()` is used.

Comment: `Union` already removes the duplicates, no reason for `Distinct`

Comment: Thanks, now I see it in docs. The `Distinct` would be necessary only if `Concat` is used.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you mipe34 and Magnus!
(== in join clause must be replaced by 'equals' but apart from that, it was plug and play!)

Comment: Yes of course. I had broken intelli-sense when there was unknown entities ;-) . I will correct my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you are trying to find **s.StructureId** in database tables and you are bringing them to Application layer.

Maybe you'd better push all of your loginc in SQL Function Or SP and get final result only to application layer?

Comment: Hi Michael, I was just using my unit testing framework as a basis for trying out the queries before starting the actual implementaton. But thanks ;)